# Using dplyr collapse rows taking condition from another numeric column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

An example df:

```
experiment = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
count = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1)
df = cbind.data.frame(experiment, count)
```

Desired output:

```
experiment_1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
freq = c(1,1,3,2,1) # frequency
freq_per = c(20,20,60,66.6,33.3) # frequency percent
df_1 = cbind.data.frame(experiment_1, freq, freq_per)
```

I want to do the following:

- 1. Group df using experiment
  2. Calculate freq using the count column
  3. Calculate freq_per
  4. Calculate sum of freq_per for all observations with count >= 3

I have the following code. How do I do the step 4?

```
freq_count = df %>% dplyr::group_by(experiment, count) %>% summarize(freq=n()) %>% na.omit() %>% mutate(freq_per=freq/sum(freq)*100)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more concise approach but I would suggest collapsing your count in a new column using `mutate()` and `ifelse()` and then summarising:

```
freq_count %>%
  mutate(collapsed_count = ifelse(count >= 3, 3, count)) %>%
  group_by(collapsed_count, add = TRUE) %>%       # adds a 2nd grouping var 
  summarise(freq = sum(freq), freq_per = (sum(freq_per))) %>% 
  select(-collapsed_count)       # dropped to match your df_1.
```

Also, just fyi, for step 2 you might consider the `count()` function if you're keen to save some keystrokes. Also `tibble()` or `data.frame()` are likely better options than calling the dataframe method of `cbind` explicitly to create a data frame.